# Html select option lost data after submit

Tags: html, plsql

i have two select option with some data:

```
<select id="S1" name="S1">
  <option value="id1">data1</option>
  <option value="id2">data2</option>
  <option value="id3">data3</option>
</select>

<select id="S2" name="S2">
  // data for selected value in S1
</select>
```

When i choose one option, i make a submit with the data to fill a second select option, but when i do this submit i lost the selected value of the first select option. How can i keep the selected value for the first select?

**Update:** i use mod_plsql, that is html languaje in a plsql procedure.

With a cursor i get the data:

```
CURSOR c_departamento IS
SELECT *
FROM sib_s_lugares_geograficos
WHERE tipo ='DE';
```

And after i fill the select one with a loop:

```
htp.p(' 
<select name="opt_departamento" value="'||OPT_DEPARTAMENTO||'" style="width: 135px" >');
FOR regDep IN c_departamento LOOP
htp.p(
'<option selected value="' || regDep.codigo || '">' || regDep.descripcion || '</option>');
END LOOP;
END IF;
 </select>');
```

I do the submit because i have another Cursor to get the data for the second select one, when i do the submit, mod_plsql call again the procedure and it paint the html, when it happen I get the correct value for the second select but i lost the value selected for the first.

Comment: What platform? What computer language?

Comment: What are you sing for youe server side scripting?

Comment: All plataforms, Language mod_plsql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way but it works.

1. Download the plugin for Jquery:

   [Jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)
2. In the element put a onclick event, i use a input element:

   > input name="btnaccion" onclick="setCookieDepartamento();" type="submit" value="ciudad"
3. It call this function, saving the value of the select in a cookie:

   > function setCookieDepartamento(){
   >   var select = document.getElementById("opt_departamento");
   >   var valor = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   >   $.cookie("departamento", valor);
   >   }
4. Call this function after submit, getting the value saved and setting in the select option:

   > function getCookieDepartamento(){
   >        var departamento = $.cookie("departamento");
   >        var element = document.getElementById("opt_departamento");
   >        element.value = departamento;
   >        $.cookie("departamento", null);
   >     }
5. That's All!

**Before submit:**
[image: Before]

**After submit:** 
[image: After]

Answer (score 2):

Using your server-side language of choice, you will need to add the `selected="selected"` attribute to the selected S1 option.

For example, if the user selects id2, output this HTML:

```
<select name="S1">
  <option value="id1">data1</option>
  <option value="id2" selected="selected">data2</option>
  <option value="id3">data3</option>
</select>

<select id="S2">
  // data for selected value in S1
</select>
```

In PHP, you could do something like this:

```
<?php $s1 = isset($_POST["S1"]) ? $_POST["S1"] : null; ?>

<option value="id1"<?= $s1 == "id1" ? "selected" : "" ?>>data1</option>
<option value="id2"<?= $s1 == "id2" ? "selected" : "" ?>>data2</option>
<option value="id3"<?= $s1 == "id3" ? "selected" : "" ?>>data3</option>
```

Ideally, though, the code you use to generate the select would also output the selected attribute.

I'm not familiar with PL/SQL, but something *like* this should work:

```
htp.p('<select name="opt_departamento" style="width: 135px">');
FOR regDep IN c_departamento LOOP
    htp.p('<option value="' || regDep.codigo || '"');
    IF regDep.codigo=OPT_DEPARTAMENTO THEN
        htp.p(' selected');
    END IF;
    htp.print('">' || regDep.descripcion || '</option>');
END LOOP;
htp.p('</select>');
```

Comment: Thanks, you said it! "the code you use to generate the select would also output the selected attribute", ¡I don't know how mod_plsql can output the selected attribute!.

Comment: Edited. That's the gist of it—I'm not familiar with PL/SQL myself. Make sense? (Also, why are you outputting a value on the select element?)

Comment: I'm outputting because the value is submit to procedure, To make a Insert for example, i use that value like a foreing key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it don't work in this case, but it helped in another issue on my program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `select` elements `name` attributes. Only fields with `name` attributes contribute to the form data set sent to a server. The `id` attribute does not affect this. You can use the same value for both attributes if you like, e.g.

```
<select id="S1" name="S1">
```

Comment: I give the name attribute, (in mod_plsql) i use the attribute name to share data to plsql variable, the procedure use this attribute to get the data of the html element.