# Keep selected option (form/select) after refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, smarty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Html select option lost data after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704066/html-select-option-lost-data-after-submit)

I have a select menu that should keep the selected option after the page refresh. This is the example:

```
<select id="form_frame" name="frame" onchange="getData(this);"/>
   <option value="data1" selected="selected">Data 1</option>
   <option value="data2">Data 2</option>
</select>
```

Function getData just pull info to the user.

I'm using Smarty/php for the dynamic content.

Open to advice, thanks!

Comment: You could look into using a cookie or localStorage.

Comment: local storage if browsers older than IE8 are'nt an issue, cookies if they are.

Comment: An example of localStorage usage for this?

Comment: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#storage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How it's done with local storage :

```
$(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('form_frame')) {
        $("#form_frame option").eq(localStorage.getItem('form_frame')).prop('selected', true);
    }

    $("#form_frame").on('change', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('form_frame', $('option:selected', this).index());
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uu6s7/)

Comment: My friend this option works for the menu, but the content pulled with the function getData onchange, doesn't update after refresh

Comment: No it does'nt, but it's impossible for me to know what that function does, returns or inserts?

Comment: It's a javascript function that shows and hide some objects: for example document.getElementById('data1').style.display = 'block';

Comment: I'm guessing you figured it out, but you basically have to store some value, could just be 0 or 1, and check if that value exists in localstorage on page load, and then set the visiblity to block or none based on that.

Comment: I add a second line in the first if with: jQuery("#form_frame option").change(); This triggers the onchange event when necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put the id or value of the selected option element in your php session( `$_SESSION['selected_option_id']`), In this way this value is passed through all the pages. And then change on the code that generates the option elements check agains `$_SESSION['selected_option_id']` and if it matches one then set the selected attribute in the option element.

Sessions is a good way to share values between requests since HTTP is a stateless protocol.

I prefer session before localStorage and cookies because those ones may not be available or enabled in the clients browser. The session is a feature of apache/php and are supported on the servers side.

[PHP Session Handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cookies. However, if you want it to work it for users that won't accept cookies from your site, append the url with a hash-tag. Onchange of the select  field you update the hash-tag. Onload of the page, you check for a present hash-tag and set the select to the option whose value matches the one of the hash-tag.